# Mocha how to expose a node controller function to test script

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js

Here is my `foo-controller.js`.

```
module.exports = function(params) {

    var router = require('express').Router();
    var db = params.db
    var controller = {};

    controller.getFoo = function (req, res) {
        // returns something
    }

    router.get('/foo', controller.getFoo);

    return router;

};
```

and here is my `test.js`.

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var bar = require('../api/controllers/bar/foo-controller');

console.log("Test", bar) // <- this returns the whole foo-controlelr.js

describe('Foo', function() {
    it('should blah blah', function() {

    });
});
```

But every time I to use `bar.getFoo()` <- the function I wanted to test. It returns the error `has no method 'getFoo'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the controller's getFoo function would require you to export this function via module.exports. But the code above does not export the controller but the router which is perfectly fine since the router is used to mount the router in express.

For testing your controller you might split routing/route definition and controller in it's own modules:

`foo-controller.js`

```
module.exports = function(params) {
  var db = params.db
  var controller = {};

  controller.getFoo = function (req, res) {
    // returns something
  }
  return controller;

};
```

`foo-router.js`

```
var fooController = require('./foo-controller');

module.exports = function(params) {

  var router = require('express').Router();

  var controller = fooController(params);

  router.get('/foo', controller.getFoo);

  return router;
};
```

This enables you to test the controller without the router.

Another approach to test the code could be to do an "integration" test, testing the router and the controller together. Using a tool like supertest (https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) you can write your integration test just like:

```
var request = require('supertest');
var express = require('express');
var fooRouter = require('.path/to/router/foo');

describe('Foo', function() {
  it('should blah blah', function(done) {

    var app = express();

    app.use('/', fooRouter(params));

    request(app)
      .get('/foo')
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res){
        if (err) throw err;
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The advantage of this approach is that your testing route definition plus controller.

Comment: So should I eliminate `mocha`?

Comment: No, this test still uses mocha (see describe, it). Supertest is just a small framework to test express apps from HTTP request to controller logic

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for this. It helped me a lot.

Comment: One more question, will this approach be good in big scaled apps? In terms of `controller`, `router` format?

Comment: That question is a bit too broad to be answered here - probably that is more a question that can be discussed but not answered. You could take a look at https://github.com/npm/newww which uses hapi but has some nice ideas of splitting route definition and logic.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I require the routers on my `app.use()`?

Comment: Hi it's a little bit confusing. On your answer on `test.js` the line `var fooRouter = require('../api/controllers/bar/foo-controller');` you declared `fooRouter` but requiring the `foo-controller` so which should it be?

Comment: Fixed it - it's now requiring an abstract /path/to/router/foo.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101756/discussion-between-saintedlama-and-the-green-foxx).